# API to check my remaining balance in Google Translation API

Tags: google-translation-api

I have enabled Google Translation API and I am using it from quite some time.
Once I exceed the limit I get a message saying I have exceeded the limit for today.
Is there any way I can get the remaining amount in my account?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas
If you exceed your quota, you will receive a 403 error message from the Translation API. This message is Daily Limit Exceeded if you exceed the daily limit, or User Rate Limit Exceeded if you exceed one of the "characters per 100 seconds" quota.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [API Dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring#using_the_api_dashboard) to monitor your API usage, which include your Quotas metrics. In this way, you can validate the **Character per day** and **Characters per 100 seconds** amounts that have been processed by the API. You can follow the steps listed below to access to this Quota section:

1. Navigate to [APIs & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) option in the upper left corner menu of your web console.
2. The API Dashboard will open and the Active APIs will be displayed below the **Activity charts**.
3. Click on the [Google Cloud Translation API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/overview) row in order to show the API overview UI.
4. Select the **Quotas tab** located in the header section of the API window.
5. You can use the **Characters drop-down** to select the **Character per day** and **Characters per 100 seconds**.
6. The characters processed amounts will be displayed at the chart as well as the **Quotas limits** values. You can use this information to determine the remaining balance of your project.

Comment: These don't look like "remaining balance" to me. Their pricing is "Free first 500,000 characters* PER MONTH". So where is this information available?